# Android ActionBarSherlock detect long press on Home menu item

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

In ABS, i am using home as back button or up navigation. Now I have a requirement that if user does a long press on the home/up button indicator in actionbar for long time, i need to display the home screen. For normal press the up button would serve as a back flow. I did not find any particular method to override. Currently i am handling in onOptionsItemSelected.

Tried to search in StackOverflow. Didn't find any solid example.

**Update:**
I tried to use below code, but in that scenario, single click was not working on device. Though in emulator both clicks were working properly. Any hints?

```
    View homeItem = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
    if(homeItem!=null){
        Log.d("homemenuitem","got it");
        View homeParent  = (View)homeItem.getParent();
        homeParent.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("homemenuitem","long click got it");
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it thanks to your sample code.
You might not need the solution anymore, but I would like to write it for others. :-)

You can just edit one line:

`View homeParent  = (View)homeItem.getParent().getParent();`

Actually, the view is LinearLayout that contains Home icon and title TextView.
It works for at least API LV14, but I don't know other version.
 (ActionBar's view hierarchy might be different depending on API LV)